# LMFIT vs. Scipy Why am I getting different results in minimize

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, minimize, lmfit

In short, I have data I'm trying to fit, and LMFIT and Scipy give 2 different solutions, with LMFIT being significantly worse.

Just some detail as to what is going on:

The "model" is a population weighted average. The "populations" are derived from 4 variables (the adjustable parameters). There are 2 independent "models" (n and h), but these are combined at the very end. The residuals is a combination of the residuals of both of these models against their respective data.

Assume the math is correct. The question is then why the different solutions when given identical functions, variables, bounds, and methods.

Given this MVE

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as so
from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsmr
from lmfit import minimize,Parameters
from lmfit.printfuncs import report_fit

data_1=[[117.417, 117.423, 117.438, 117.501], [124.16, 124.231, 124.089, 124.1], [115.632, 115.645, 115.828, 115.947], [118.314, 118.317, 118.287, 118.228], [108.407, 108.419, 108.396, 108.564]]
data_2=[[9.05, 9.044, 9.057, 9.079], [9.178, 9.167, 9.16, 9.176], [7.888, 7.893, 7.911, 7.895], [7.198, 7.202, 7.197, 7.213], [7.983, 7.976, 7.979, 8.02]]
def get_populations_lmfit(initial,io):
    k,k1,x,y=initial['kvar'],initial['k1var'],initial['xvar'],initial['yvar']
    kx,k1x=k*x,k1*x
    ky,k1y=k*y,k1*y
    kxy,k1xy=k*x*y,k1*x*y   
    partial_free_concentration_WT=(np.sqrt((k*k1)**2+(8*io*k*k1)+(8*io*k*k1**2))-(k*k1))/(4*(1+k1))
    partial_closed_concentration_WT=(((4*io)+(4*io*k1))/(4*(1+k1)**2))-(partial_free_concentration_WT/(1+k1))
    partial_open_concentration_WT=k1*partial_closed_concentration_WT
    partial_free_concentration_L273A=(np.sqrt((kx*k1x)**2+(8*io*kx*k1x)+(8*io*kx*k1x**2))-(kx*k1x))/(4*(1+k1x))
    partial_closed_concentration_L273A=(((4*io)+(4*io*k1x))/(4*(1+k1x)**2))-(partial_free_concentration_L273A/(1+k1x))
    partial_open_concentration_L273A=k1x*partial_closed_concentration_L273A
    partial_free_concentration_I272A=(np.sqrt((ky*k1y)**2+(8*io*ky*k1y)+(8*io*ky*k1y**2))-(ky*k1y))/(4*(1+k1y))
    partial_closed_concentration_I272A=(((4*io)+(4*io*k1y))/(4*(1+k1y)**2))-(partial_free_concentration_I272A/(1+k1y))
    partial_open_concentration_I272A=k1y*partial_closed_concentration_I272A
    partial_free_concentration_ILAA=(np.sqrt((kxy*k1xy)**2+(8*io*kxy*k1xy)+(8*io*kxy*k1xy**2))-(kxy*k1xy))/(4*(1+k1xy))
    partial_closed_concentration_ILAA=(((4*io)+(4*io*k1xy))/(4*(1+k1xy)**2))-(partial_free_concentration_ILAA/(1+k1xy))
    partial_open_concentration_ILAA=k1xy*partial_closed_concentration_ILAA
    local_chi2=0
    for experimental_shifts_n,experimental_shifts_h in zip(data_1,data_2):
        populations=np.array([[partial_free_concentration_WT,partial_open_concentration_WT,partial_closed_concentration_WT],[partial_free_concentration_L273A,partial_open_concentration_L273A,partial_closed_concentration_L273A],[partial_free_concentration_I272A,partial_open_concentration_I272A,partial_closed_concentration_I272A],[partial_free_concentration_ILAA,partial_open_concentration_ILAA,partial_closed_concentration_ILAA]])
        experimental_shifts_n=(np.array([experimental_shifts_n])/10)*800
        experimental_shifts_h=(np.array([experimental_shifts_h]))*800
        least_squared_fit_n=lsmr(populations/io,experimental_shifts_n,maxiter=10)
        least_squared_fit_h=lsmr(populations/io,experimental_shifts_h,maxiter=10)
        local_chi2+=((least_squared_fit_n[3])**2+least_squared_fit_h[3]**2)
    return local_chi2

def get_populations_scipy(initial,io):
    k,k1,x,y=initial[0],initial[1],initial[2],initial[3]
    kx,k1x=k*x,k1*x
    ky,k1y=k*y,k1*y
    kxy,k1xy=k*x*y,k1*x*y
    partial_free_concentration_WT=(np.sqrt((k*k1)**2+(8*io*k*k1)+(8*io*k*k1**2))-(k*k1))/(4*(1+k1))
    partial_closed_concentration_WT=(((4*io)+(4*io*k1))/(4*(1+k1)**2))-(partial_free_concentration_WT/(1+k1))
    partial_open_concentration_WT=k1*partial_closed_concentration_WT
    partial_free_concentration_L273A=(np.sqrt((kx*k1x)**2+(8*io*kx*k1x)+(8*io*kx*k1x**2))-(kx*k1x))/(4*(1+k1x))
    partial_closed_concentration_L273A=(((4*io)+(4*io*k1x))/(4*(1+k1x)**2))-(partial_free_concentration_L273A/(1+k1x))
    partial_open_concentration_L273A=k1x*partial_closed_concentration_L273A
    partial_free_concentration_I272A=(np.sqrt((ky*k1y)**2+(8*io*ky*k1y)+(8*io*ky*k1y**2))-(ky*k1y))/(4*(1+k1y))
    partial_closed_concentration_I272A=(((4*io)+(4*io*k1y))/(4*(1+k1y)**2))-(partial_free_concentration_I272A/(1+k1y))
    partial_open_concentration_I272A=k1y*partial_closed_concentration_I272A
    partial_free_concentration_ILAA=(np.sqrt((kxy*k1xy)**2+(8*io*kxy*k1xy)+(8*io*kxy*k1xy**2))-(kxy*k1xy))/(4*(1+k1xy))
    partial_closed_concentration_ILAA=(((4*io)+(4*io*k1xy))/(4*(1+k1xy)**2))-(partial_free_concentration_ILAA/(1+k1xy))
    partial_open_concentration_ILAA=k1xy*partial_closed_concentration_ILAA
    local_chi2=0
    for experimental_shifts_n,experimental_shifts_h in zip(data_1,data_2):
        populations=np.array([[partial_free_concentration_WT,partial_open_concentration_WT,partial_closed_concentration_WT],[partial_free_concentration_L273A,partial_open_concentration_L273A,partial_closed_concentration_L273A],[partial_free_concentration_I272A,partial_open_concentration_I272A,partial_closed_concentration_I272A],[partial_free_concentration_ILAA,partial_open_concentration_ILAA,partial_closed_concentration_ILAA]])
        experimental_shifts_n=(np.array([experimental_shifts_n])/10)*800
        experimental_shifts_h=(np.array([experimental_shifts_h]))*800
        least_squared_fit_n=lsmr(populations/io,experimental_shifts_n,maxiter=10)
        least_squared_fit_h=lsmr(populations/io,experimental_shifts_h,maxiter=10)
        local_chi2+=((least_squared_fit_n[3])**2+least_squared_fit_h[3]**2)
    return local_chi2

io=270000
params=Parameters()
params.add('kvar',value=500,min=0,max=np.inf)
params.add('k1var',value=0.02,min=0,max=np.inf)
params.add('xvar',value=7,min=0,max=np.inf)
params.add('yvar',value=30,min=0,max=np.inf)
lmfit_solution=minimize(get_populations_lmfit,params,args=(io,),method='nelder',max_nfev=1000)
scipy_solution=so.minimize(get_populations_scipy,args=(io,), x0=np.array([500,0.02,7,30]),bounds=((0,np.inf),)*4,method='Nelder-Mead',options={'maxiter':1000})
print(report_fit(lmfit_solution))
print(scipy_solution)
```

You will note the solutions from scipy vs. lmfit are completely different. Not only that, the chi2 for scipy is significantly better than lmfit. I don't quite understand why however. The setup is practically identical, the conditions and bounds and methods are identical, why do they give different results? I.E. Why is LMFITs solution so much worse?

Now I know you can give LMFIT an array of residuals instead of the sum like I have, and while this does improve the solutions a bit, it's still worse than Scipy and significantly worse chi2.

Comment: Are both results valid (other than having different levels of optimality)?

Comment: I do not see any evidence for the results being different.  Where is that given?  I do see unreadable code described as a MVE.  It looks like you are looping over the data and doing a bunch of iterative least-squares fits inside a scalar objective function to be solved by scipy or lmfit.  Using an iterative solver inside an iterative solver seems very weird to me.

Comment: @Reinderien For the minimal verifiable example, yes. The answers are different, but not significantly so. This is not true in my own more complicated dataset (where lmfit gives significantly different solutions). However, from my understanding lmfit is just a scipy wrapper, as such the scipy functions (e.g. minimize and its methods) should work identical in lmfit as they do in scipy. So if an identical problem is given to both lmfit and scipy. you should get an identical solution. In the above case, while you get similar answers, they are not exactly the same.

Comment: My concern is am I misunderstanding something about lmfit? Am I setting it up incorrectly? Why are my solutions not exactly the same despite all the conditions/methods being the same? The only difference in the above 2 function is one uses scipy, one uses lmfit. Everything else is identical. I want to make sure lmfit is working properly before I go further and replace scipy with lmfit (this was my simplified test case to ensure I can get the same answer with lmfit as I do with scipy, so then I can play around with lmfit to optimize my solution)

Comment: but you have not shown that they are different.  In fact, you have shown zero output, so you have not shown anything.  Your script even has print() functions for the output of the lmfit fit_report and the scipy solution, and you DO NOT SHOW THEM.  You say "You will note the solutions from scipy vs. lmfit are completely different....".  Nope, I do not note that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking the wrong questions. `lmfit` has no advantage here, so the easy decision is to scrap it and use scipy directly; but - your current code is cursed, so that should be fixed up. Vectorise, factor out common expressions, and reduce to a single inner `lstsq` call. The following shows that the old and new methods are numerically equivalent to ~13 significant digits, but the new method will be faster and is more simple to debug. Among many other reasons, your old code went through all of the trouble of doing many inner linear fits, but then always threw away the result.

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as so

data_1 = np.array([
    [117.417, 117.423, 117.438, 117.501],
    [124.160, 124.231, 124.089, 124.100],
    [115.632, 115.645, 115.828, 115.947],
    [118.314, 118.317, 118.287, 118.228],
    [108.407, 108.419, 108.396, 108.564],
])
data_2 = np.array([
    [9.050, 9.044, 9.057, 9.079],
    [9.178, 9.167, 9.160, 9.176],
    [7.888, 7.893, 7.911, 7.895],
    [7.198, 7.202, 7.197, 7.213],
    [7.983, 7.976, 7.979, 8.020],
])


def setup_for_chi(initial: np.ndarray, io: float) -> tuple[
    np.ndarray,
    np.ndarray,
    np.ndarray,
]:
    k, k1, x, y = initial
    xy1 = np.array((1, x, y, x*y))
    k4 = k*xy1
    k14 = k1*xy1

    partial_free_concentration = (
        np.sqrt(
            (k4*k14)**2
            + 8*io*k4*k14*(1 + k14)
        ) - k4*k14
    )/(4*(1 + k14))

    partial_closed_concentration = (
        4*io + 4*io*k14
    )/(
        4*(1 + k14)**2
    ) - partial_free_concentration/(1 + k14)

    partial_open_concentration = k14 * partial_closed_concentration

    populations = np.stack((
        partial_free_concentration,
        partial_open_concentration,
        partial_closed_concentration,
    ), axis=1)

    return (
        np.broadcast_to(populations/io, (len(data_1), *populations.shape)),
        data_1*80,
        data_2*800,
    )


def fit_populations(initial: np.ndarray, io: float) -> tuple[np.ndarray, float]:
    populations_io, experimental_shifts_n, experimental_shifts_h = setup_for_chi(initial, io)

    # 4x3
    A = populations_io[0, ...]

    # 4x10
    b = np.vstack((
        experimental_shifts_n,
        experimental_shifts_h,
    )).T

    x, chi2, rank, s = np.linalg.lstsq(a=A, b=b, rcond=None)
    return x, chi2.sum()


def get_populations(initial: np.ndarray, io: float) -> float:
    x, chi2 = fit_populations(initial, io)
    return chi2


def get_populations_old(initial,io, debug=False):
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsmr
    k,k1,x,y=initial[0],initial[1],initial[2],initial[3]
    kx,k1x=k*x,k1*x
    ky,k1y=k*y,k1*y
    kxy,k1xy=k*x*y,k1*x*y
    partial_free_concentration_WT=(np.sqrt((k*k1)**2+(8*io*k*k1)+(8*io*k*k1**2))-(k*k1))/(4*(1+k1))
    partial_closed_concentration_WT=(((4*io)+(4*io*k1))/(4*(1+k1)**2))-(partial_free_concentration_WT/(1+k1))
    partial_open_concentration_WT=k1*partial_closed_concentration_WT
    partial_free_concentration_L273A=(np.sqrt((kx*k1x)**2+(8*io*kx*k1x)+(8*io*kx*k1x**2))-(kx*k1x))/(4*(1+k1x))
    partial_closed_concentration_L273A=(((4*io)+(4*io*k1x))/(4*(1+k1x)**2))-(partial_free_concentration_L273A/(1+k1x))
    partial_open_concentration_L273A=k1x*partial_closed_concentration_L273A
    partial_free_concentration_I272A=(np.sqrt((ky*k1y)**2+(8*io*ky*k1y)+(8*io*ky*k1y**2))-(ky*k1y))/(4*(1+k1y))
    partial_closed_concentration_I272A=(((4*io)+(4*io*k1y))/(4*(1+k1y)**2))-(partial_free_concentration_I272A/(1+k1y))
    partial_open_concentration_I272A=k1y*partial_closed_concentration_I272A
    partial_free_concentration_ILAA=(np.sqrt((kxy*k1xy)**2+(8*io*kxy*k1xy)+(8*io*kxy*k1xy**2))-(kxy*k1xy))/(4*(1+k1xy))
    partial_closed_concentration_ILAA=(((4*io)+(4*io*k1xy))/(4*(1+k1xy)**2))-(partial_free_concentration_ILAA/(1+k1xy))
    partial_open_concentration_ILAA=k1xy*partial_closed_concentration_ILAA
    local_chi2=0
    for experimental_shifts_n,experimental_shifts_h in zip(data_1,data_2):
        populations=np.array([[partial_free_concentration_WT,partial_open_concentration_WT,partial_closed_concentration_WT],[partial_free_concentration_L273A,partial_open_concentration_L273A,partial_closed_concentration_L273A],[partial_free_concentration_I272A,partial_open_concentration_I272A,partial_closed_concentration_I272A],[partial_free_concentration_ILAA,partial_open_concentration_ILAA,partial_closed_concentration_ILAA]])
        experimental_shifts_n=(np.array([experimental_shifts_n])/10)*800
        experimental_shifts_h=(np.array([experimental_shifts_h]))*800
        least_squared_fit_n=lsmr(populations/io,experimental_shifts_n,maxiter=10)
        least_squared_fit_h=lsmr(populations/io,experimental_shifts_h,maxiter=10)
        if debug:
            print(least_squared_fit_n[0])
            print(least_squared_fit_h[0])
        local_chi2+=((least_squared_fit_n[3])**2+least_squared_fit_h[3]**2)
    return local_chi2


io = 270_000


def new_optimize() -> None:
    print('New:')
    solution = so.minimize(
        fun=get_populations,
        args=(io,),
        x0=np.array([500, 0.02, 7, 30]),
        bounds=((0, np.inf),)*4,
        options={'maxiter': 1_000},
    )
    assert solution.success, solution.message
    print('Initial:', solution.x)
    x, chi2 = fit_populations(solution.x, io)
    print('Residual:', chi2)


def regression_test() -> None:
    popio, exp_n, exp_h = setup_for_chi(initial=np.array([500, 0.02, 7, 30]), io=io)

    assert len(popio) == 5

    for pop in popio:
        assert np.allclose(
            pop,
            np.array([
                [0.00425185, 0.01952447, 0.97622368],
                [0.02781779, 0.11939080, 0.85279142],
                [0.09698655, 0.33863005, 0.56438341],
                [0.32547629, 0.54480761, 0.1297161]],
            ),
        )

    assert np.allclose(
        np.vstack(exp_n),
        np.array([
            [9393.36, 9393.84, 9395.04, 9400.08],
            [9932.8 , 9938.48, 9927.12, 9928.  ],
            [9250.56, 9251.6 , 9266.24, 9275.76],
            [9465.12, 9465.36, 9462.96, 9458.24],
            [8672.56, 8673.52, 8671.68, 8685.12],
        ]),
    )
    assert np.allclose(
        np.vstack(exp_h),
        np.array([
            [7240. , 7235.2, 7245.6, 7263.2],
            [7342.4, 7333.6, 7328. , 7340.8],
            [6310.4, 6314.4, 6328.8, 6316. ],
            [5758.4, 5761.6, 5757.6, 5770.4],
            [6386.4, 6380.8, 6383.2, 6416. ],
        ]),
    )


def old_optimize() -> None:
    scipy_solution = so.minimize(get_populations_old, args=(io,), x0=np.array([500, 0.02, 7, 30]),
                                 bounds=((0, np.inf),) * 4, method='Nelder-Mead',
                                 options={'maxiter': 1000})
    assert scipy_solution.success, scipy_solution.message
    print('OLD -')
    print('Initial:', scipy_solution.x)
    print('Residual:', scipy_solution.fun)
    print('Inner factor:')
    get_populations_old(scipy_solution.x, io, debug=True)
    x, chi2 = fit_populations(scipy_solution.x, io)
    print('chi2 from new, to compare:', chi2)
    print('Inner factor from new:')
    print(x)
    print()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    regression_test()
    old_optimize()
    new_optimize()
```

```
OLD -
Initial: [8.43488198e+02 3.73287986e-02 1.24710782e+00 5.87182669e+00]
Residual: 61.1805732870818
Inner factor:
[13574.53212153  8420.98162826  9397.58024441]
[22773.61024014  3634.75940246  7252.0978788 ]
[11112.84033704  9604.77003648  9938.98540985]
[23099.71790687  3549.89959355  7358.35542221]
[14598.2687031   8102.07994522  9252.20266122]
[-9605.44078682 10177.17124497  6290.34488533]
[ 5574.63331111 10364.43102419  9461.76279142]
[17134.2141557   3071.33941429  5772.55420423]
[20950.90064132  5776.67678267  8686.4137172 ]
[37642.15814366  -977.72464129  6417.34277753]
chi2 from new, to compare: 61.18057328708239
Inner factor from new:
[[13574.53212153 11112.84033703 14598.26870309  5574.63331116
  20950.90064131 22773.61024013 23099.71790684 -9605.44078684
  17134.21415572 37642.15814367]
 [ 8420.98162821  9604.77003642  8102.07994516 10364.43102393
   5776.6767826   3634.75940237  3549.89959343 10177.17124489
   3071.33941434  -977.72464127]
 [ 9397.58024442  9938.98540985  9252.20266123  9461.76279145
   8686.4137172   7252.09787881  7358.35542223  6290.34488534
   5772.55420422  6417.34277752]]

New:
Initial: [4.99999627e+02 1.02141914e-01 1.65423176e+00 3.11581574e+01]
Residual: 61.18057338613728
```

Comment: Thank you for the improvements, but lmfit does have many improvements. The most immediate is it's simplicity to use different methods and outputs for error analysis. If I want to change between different methods such as a Nelder-Mead in my example or LM, I'd need to change the output. Not to mention entire setups for numdifftools for various stats and error analysis that is already built into lmfit. I do like the vectorization, definitely cleans it up, but I'm a bit confused as to what the purpose of the regression test is?

Comment: _what the purpose of the regression test is?_ - So that as I changed the implement station I could guarantee equivalence (you should do this too).

Comment: _If I want to change between different methods such as a Nelder-Mead in my example or LM, I'd need to change the output_ - which output? Changing methods is as simple as one string parameter to `minimize`.

Comment: minimize does not have least squares methods (such as levenberg-marquardt). I'd need to change to least squares and have to change the formats. The same is true for using global solvers such as dual annealing or basinhopping (granted these are small changes, but it's really convenient to have one function that does all). lmfit wraps minimize, the global solvers, and least squares all into one. It's quite clean and convenient